# jQuery: can I use z-index to solve this?

Tags: jquery, hover, z-index

Before going into the problem, I thought it'd be best to describe what I'm trying to do... if you go to this fiddle you can see it in (although with problems present) in action:

http://jsfiddle.net/jhacks/xCcdn/99/ (it needs to have jQuery selected to work)

The problem I'm trying to solve with this post is pretty blatantly screwed up in the fiddle. Due to the ordering of my html, the tooltip (topTip) pushes the notification icon (topIconNew) downwards when it is present. Obviously, the notification icon should remain stationary. I do not want to reorder the html, as the notification icon will not always be present. Therefore, they can all be positioned using the same class. I think the solution should be z-index? However, my attempts at using CSS to solve it don't seem to work... I assume there is something I must do in the jQuery perhaps?

If anyone could help me here it'd be greatly appreciated. Let me know if I need to be more clear with what I'm looking to do here and I'll try to better explain. Thanks!

Comment: You've asked this exact question before, I am quite sure of it. Can you strip your text to a *bare* minimum? I can't extract your question from this text.

Comment: I have edited the code and my question. I appreciate the feedback. I see now that the question can be approached with less code and text to work through. Hopefully my edits help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I get the question correctly. I would recommend to use absolute positioning to keep the icons where they are when the tooltip is shown. You should also set the .topIcon position to 'relative' so the absolute position of the tooltip relates to it. The changes will be somewhat like this. (Not sure about the actual numbers for the position.

```
.topIcon {
    position: relative;
}

.topIconNew {
    bottom:-20px;
    right:14px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that CSS tidbit about position. I actually did not realize that if the parent item was relative that a absolute position child would be in relation to the parent. That seems like it'd probably work. I'll try that.

Answer (score 2):

Change the two CSS properties of `.topTip` to these:

```
position: absolute;
top: 40px;
right: 0px;
```

And add this CSS property to `.topIcon`:

```
position: relative;
```

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/karalamalar/xCcdn/100/)

Comment: Ah okay. This is what cellcortix said above as well. That seems to be a good way to approach this... I appreciate that. I think it's the best solution. I learned something new about CSS. It'll be very useful elsewhere for me too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps give this a try: http://jsfiddle.net/sdPVG/

I've added a negative margins to compensat for the box height and border width. This seems a bit hackish, but is actually very well supported across many different browsers.

Hoep that helps!

Comment: Here a couple of references that you might find helpful: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/negativemargins, http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/27/the-definitive-guide-to-using-negative-margins/

Comment: Ah okay. So you used negative margins to push topTip to the position below topIconNew. I see. That would seem to work also... unless the topIconNew and topTip need to overlap? Then I think the problem would still be there? Just asking for future knowledge.

Comment: Yeah, basically the negative margins make the element take up zero space; you are essentially saying if it is 100px wide, I'll just subtract 100px, resulting in a 0px impact on content flow. This is a nice little trick to use when you want an element in the content flow to benefit from the positioning without impacting anything else. Even if you needed topIconNew and topTip to overlap, this would still work, it would just boil down to the values you assign to top and left.

Answer (score 1):

change

```
<a href="icon.html"><img src="icons/icon.png" /></a>

<div class="topTip">
    <div class="topTipText">hello</div>
</div>
<div class="topDrop">What's up</div>
<div class="topIconNew"></div>
```

to

```
<a href="icon.html"><img src="icons/icon.png" /></a>
<div class="topIconNew"></div>
<div class="topTip">
    <div class="topTipText">hello</div>
</div>
<div class="topDrop">What's up</div>
```

also added .topIconOld as spacer for where you don't won't red icon to preserve spacing. Hopefully you'll see in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4JGx3/) *it's the first time I have used it for sharing etc :-)*

Comment: Thank you for that! I appreciate all the help here everyone. :)